# Linker error not finding destructor when a function is templated

Tags: c++, c++11, linker, clang, linker-errors

I have this weird bug which I cannot wrap my head around. I've reduced it to a simple example. I can fix it by creating an empty destructor, but I would really like to know what is going on.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>

struct test {
    inline test()
    {}

    const std::function<void()> f;
    const int universe = 42;
};

template<size_t n = 1>
inline void do_test(const test& t = {}) {
    printf("%d\n", t.universe);
}

int main(int, char**) {
//  test t;
    do_test();
    return 0;
}
```

This will not compile, outputting the error:

```
clang++ -O3 -std=c++1z -stdlib=libc++ -Wall main.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "test::~test()", referenced from:
      _main in main-df96d9.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

If you either, uncomment the line where I create the `test t;` object, or remove the template parameter from `do_test()`, it will compile.

Note that the example is simplistic, the actual software requires the custom constructor, the template parameter, etc.

Any idea why it is complaining about finding the destructor?

Comment: [Proof here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbf534d106b15cf2)

Comment: Looks like a Clang bug.  GCC doesn't have a problem with this code.

Comment: Compiled in VS2015, seems ok here. It must be clang-specific then. Try initializing the "const test&" with "test()" instead of "{}", see if it's a specific bug related to initializer list. What's probably happening is that the compiler is failing to note that it needs to create a default destructor for the class when you've only ever refered to the class by reference, and the initializer list => constructor auto-conversion only kicks in once it's resolved the details of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed bug in clang < 4 it seems.